# Run python script using existing ipython kernel without console

Tags: console, kernel, ipython

I can run a python script from a bash shell like so:

```
>> python script.py
```

I can also start an iPython kernel and connect multiple iPython consoles to the same kernel like so:

```
>> ipython kernel
...
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
--existing kernel-8987.json
```

then, for as many consoles as I would like, I execute

```
>> jupyter console --existing kernel-8987.json
```

However, what I would like to do is start a kernel, but then run scripts *without* opening a console. I'd like to do something like this:

```
>> ipython --existing kernel-8987.json script.py
```

Is this possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Extending on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630078/5267751) and use the [`%run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) magic command<sup>1</sup>, it's possible to do this (which works for multiple-line scripts):

```sh
$ jupyter console --simple-prompt --existing kernel-8987.json <<< '%run script.py'
```

or (on Windows where `<<<` doesn't work)

```
> echo %run script.py | jupyter console --simple-prompt --existing kernel-8987.json
```

Unfortunately, this method still prints some redundant prompt (`In[1]:`) on the console.

---

Alternatively, using Python API: (create a script to execute this Python code) (on my machine, this method is much faster)

```py
from jupyter_client.manager import KernelManager
manager=KernelManager(connection_file="full path to connection file.json")
manager.load_connection_file()
manager.client().execute("commands to execute")
```

The commands to execute might span multiple lines, or have the form `%run file.py`.

There's also `silent=True, store_history=False` as parameters to `execute()`.

The full path to the connection file can be found as

- `Path(jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_runtime_dir()) / "kernel-8987.json"`, or
- `jupyter_client.connect.find_connection_file("kernel-8987.json")` (find file with specific name), or
- `jupyter_client.connect.find_connection_file()` (find the latest file)

See also [`jupyter-client` documentation](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/client.html).

Disclaimer: Some of the code are taken from jupyter-vim plugin, and `manager.load_connection_file` and `connect.find_connection_file` appears to be undocumented.

---

<sup>1</sup>: As mentioned in the documentation, the file is executed in a new namespace unless you use `-i`.

Comment: You can use `connection_file = jupyter_client.connect.find_connection_file()` if you don't want to provide a path to the kernel file and would like your script to work as if `--existing` has been passed in the command line

Answer (score 4):

```
% jupyter console --version
6.2.0
```

I can exec **one-liners** from a file like this:

```
% jupyter console --simple-prompt --existing kernel-8987.json < script.py
```

Comment: kernel-21247 is the kernel name or the .json file name?

Comment: @ArrozconTomate the json file is the moniker for the kernel, as described in the question. I've update to show where the `script.py` goes. But still note it would only accept complete one line statements, not nested blocks. At least not in the version I've tested.

Comment: How did you get the .json file? Simply by using 'jupyter kernelspec list' and browsing in the corresponding file location? or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `jupyter` has this functionality already built in.

```
$ jupyter run --existing kernel-8987.json script.py
```

I don't know if this was a feature addition since the OP, or if I was really stupid and didn't RTFM.

```
$ jupyter run --help
Run Jupyter kernel code.

Options
=======
...
--existing=<CUnicode>
    Connect to an already running kernel
    Default: ''
    Equivalent to: [--JupyterConsoleApp.existing]
```

The other answers will run the code in the existing kernel, but still open a console in the process. The `run` subcommand does exactly what I requested: runs the code *without* opening an interactive console.

Comment: Looks like `jupyter run` was first added in Aug 8, 2016 in version 5.0.0. [Add jupyter-run command to jupyter_client collection · jupyter/jupyter_client@08d6c30](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/commit/08d6c300dbd08f0ef14ea1bb62608c84ee2504a4) // my answer using Python API does not open a new console though.